# how to append/union two insert queries into 1 row in sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i have a problem where i dont know how to append/union two insert queries into 1 row in sql server...

my queries currently like this

```
id        qty      name        size       remarks          condition
=============================================================================
1         2        wheel      null       null              null
2        null      null        345       need service      ok
3        null      null        678       condem size       no
```

row 2,3 is a looping query because i adding textbox dynamically.the 1st row is the fix textbox which user enter once only.so i want to combine these data to sql database.suppose it has to be 2 rows only,

Comment: how should be your desired output?

Comment: it will be the 2nd row lift up to 1st row,then 3rd row is the 2nd row                                                                         id        qty      name        size       remarks          condition
=============================================================================
1         2        wheel      345       need service      ok
2         2        wheel      678       condem size       no

Comment: right now that is the only way i can insert data to database..but later i dont know how to display the data..i want it to be as i mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways.

### Using a stored procedure

Create a stored procedure for insertion of records of your 'looping query'. For example

`addDynamicRecord(@size int, @remarks varchar(MAX), @condition varchar(MAX))`

For each 'dynamic record' (using your terminology) instead of executing `INSERT` you will call this procedure for records #2, #3, etc. In the procedure, there will be a check whether a dynamic record was already merged with your fixed record (#1). If not,  `UPDATE` record #1 with `@size`, `@remarks`, `@condition`. Else just `INSERT` `@size`, `@remarks`, `@condition` into a new record.

### Using `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger

This will perform the same actions as the stored procedure proposed above, but they will launch when you use standard `INSERT` statement. For more information on `INSTEAD OF INSERT`, please check here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx

Generally I recommend first approach, it is cleaner, keeping standard `INSERT`'s into your table intact.